# Can we link a new RCU with an old weblogic Domain

Tags: oracle, weblogic, rcu

Can we link a new RCU with an old weblogic Domain. Imagine a scenario where I remove a RCU from DB but the domain is already there. After creating a new RCU how do I sync/reconfigure it with old Domain?

Comment: In 11g, you just have to update your datasource URL, Username and replace encrypted password.(Using java weblogic.security.Encrypt <password>).
In 12c, there are additional steps where you will update jps-config.xml, jps-config-jse.xml and update bootstrap credentials using modifyBootStrapCredential in WLST

Comment: Can I get a document or a blog?